# Can't find installed jre page in Eclipse indigo IDE for C/C++ Developers

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I am using mac lion and eclipse indigo. I am trying set it up for java development. I found that I need to install a separate jdk from apple and do some configurations in eclipse. The problem is I can't find the installed jre page under Eclipse->preference->java. I am using a version of eclipse for C/C++ downloaded from the eclipse official page. I suppose that is the problem.

I just downloaded and tried another version of eclipse for java and I can find this page. This is odd. I don't want keep two eclipse. Does anyone know how to find the installed jre page in the eclipse for C/C++?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JRE and java-related pages appear in the Java edition of Eclipse.  If you downloaded the C/C++ version of Eclipse already and are happy with that, you need to install the Java modules for Eclipse within the C/C++ version.  Likely, the easiest way to do that is to install the WTP module.

Go to Help->Install New Software... and specify the Indigo WTP update site http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/

You can get more info on WTP [here](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/development/news/main.php).

Answer (score 0):

If you install the Java version you can install the C++ tools (CDT) I am sure there is a [JDT](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/) for Java too but I would need to reinstall eclipse to test.

[image: CDT]